# How do retrieve a value from a list that the user chooses to retrieve

Tags: python, python-3.x

For a current program that I am working on, I want the user to input a string that is located inside of a list. The string that is in the list is supposed to get retrieved. How do I do this?

Comment: Do you need to check if user input is the same of one of the list's element?

Comment: Do you have any code you've written that you can show? Your question is pretty broad. Also what about the case where the string entered doesn't match the string in the list? And you should also think about if it has to be case sensitive or not.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
lst = ['aaaa', 'bbbb', 'abab']
ip = input("Provide a string: ").rstrip()
print("Found in strings: ", ", ".join([i for i in lst if ip in i]))
```

Output

```
Provide a string: ab
Found in strings:  abab
```

and

```
Provide a string: a
Found in strings:  aaaa, abab
```